# Ubuntu persistant LiveUSB

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, live-usb, persistence

I have a LiveUSB of Ubuntu 14.04 on a 2GB flash drive that I want to use for computer diagnosis and repair. I want to know how to add things like an anti-virus scanner, malware removal and hard drive utilities. Can someone tell me what tools they use or would recommend and how I would do that? Step by step pictures would be nice to look at.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure which Linux Distro it's based on, but if you've never tried Kasperky's Rescue disk, it's quite good and one could easily put this on a Live USB (http://rescuedisk.kaspersky-labs.com/rescuedisk/updatable/kav_rescue_10.iso). It is quite full featured and updates itself when run. If you are dealing with Windows machines, it's worth a look at UBCD4WIN (http://www.ubcd4win.com/) or http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/  I realize you asekd about Ubuntu but these other solutions are very evolved and worth considering... P.S, there's also this: http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/

Comment: I just put lubuntu 14.04 on a flash drive and added dc3dd and testdisk. You can choose between avast, bitdefender, clamav, and avg (which all have linux versions)

Comment: You might want to give KNOPPIX a try. You've probably heard of it. See http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html for downloads or, if you have a BitTorrent client like Transmission installed, http://torrent.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Windows machine, the YUMI app might work for you. It enables you to put multiple bootable iso's on one thumb drive and creates a menu to select which to boot from at start-up. Also, you can include a persistence file for Ubuntu.

More info at http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/.

I don't have pictures to post but perhaps give it a go and reply back with questions?

Answer (score 0):

For hard drive utilities dc3dd and testdisk work well together.

For antivirus you can choose Avast, AVG, Bitdefender, and Clam AV. All available for Linux ATM. ClamAV is released under the GPL.

Comment: I recommend ClamAV. It's open source and probably works the best. If you want a GUI, and I'm sure you will, install ClamTk in addition to ClamAV.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste Good point. I've also used ClamAV with good results